# Cannot install golang package in python3 ( golang libjpeg-turbo to be exact)

Tags: python-3.x, macos

So i'm trying to learn how to make gaming bots and read the following tutorial and it asked to download the following package/module : golang libjpeg-turbo
and gave the command :
brew install golang libjpeg-turbo
which does not work (neither does replacing brew with pip or conda works )
trying : pip install golang libjpeg-turbo
gives the following :

> Collecting golang     Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement golang (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for golang

i'm using python 3.6.3 on a windows machine
link to the article i'm referring (would love some suggestions for articles based on ai based bots for beginners):
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-an-ai-game-bot-using-openai-gym-and-universe-f2eb9bfbb40a

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial suggests you run the following command:

```
brew install golang libjpeg-turbo
```

This command is referencing [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), which is a package manager for MacOS.  You mentioned that you are using Windows, so there is absolutely no way this command is going to work.  Similarly, `golang` is not a python package, so `pip3 install golang` isn't going to work either.

Comment: Thanks ! I did know that it was for MacOs but perhaps thought there could be an alternative for it